# How to convert a column with datatype "list" in a JSON file to an excel table?

Tags: json, excel, export

I have bunch of JSON files and I need to convert all of them into an excel table.

I could do all the needed steps, but I get stuck with an error in the last step, which is, converting "labels" column with has a "list" data type, into a comma separated values.

[image]

[image]

Let me share a sample of similar JSON file and the screenshots to make the issue clear to all of you:

```
{
    "color":"DEFAULT","isTrashed":false,
    "isPinned":false,
    "isArchived":false,
    "textContent":"Note's sample text",
    "title":"Note's Title",
    "userEditedTimestampUsec":1633783789813000,
    "createdTimestampUsec":1619811485384000,
    "labels":
    [
        {"name":"REF"},
        {"name":"2021"}
    ]
}
```

Note, I follow many tutorials in YouTube such the following link [From 3:35 till 5:10], but it is ending with an error with me, while it is working fine with the tutor.

https://youtu.be/C9rOUvWO7cM?t=216

What I expect is to have all the columns of the mentioned file to be in one record, and for the nested variables, to be as comma separated values within the same single record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for providing an example that demonstrates the issue, and is in text format that can be easily copy pasted.

The "labels" are a `List` of `Records` where the label itself has the Field name of `name`.

But the code you show for extracting the values assumes the `List` is a list of text strings.

You can easily extract the labels as a comma-separated string by writing the M-Code directly in the advanced editor.

You should be able to adapt the code below to your data. The only thing I did that was not from the UI was the last code line before the **`in`** statement:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\new.json")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Converted to Table"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{
        {"color", type text}, {"isTrashed", type logical}, {"isPinned", type logical}, 
        {"isArchived", type logical}, {"textContent", type text}, {"title", type text}, 
        {"userEditedTimestampUsec", Int64.Type}, {"createdTimestampUsec", Int64.Type}, {"labels", type any}}),

    #"Extract Labels" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{
        {"labels", each Text.Combine(List.Accumulate(_,{},(x,y)=> x & {y[name]}),","), type text}
    })
    
in
    #"Extract Labels"
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @Ron, 

Thank you for your prompt and useful answer, I tried in through the advanced editor and it works !

As a part of my question, how to import multiple json files which has the same schema into excel, and apply that solution on it?